# Creating property to a ref bean, Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties, javabeans, ref

I have searched in this site a lot of spring.. but i'm really new to this..
so here is my question:

I have 3 main classes i'm gonna put it like this..

```
 public class User
 {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Car> cars;

    public ArrayList<Car> getCars() 
    {
       return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(ArrayList<Car> cars) 
    {
       this.cars= cars;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }
 }

 public class Car
 {
    private String type;
    private ArrayList<Wheel> wheels;

    public ArrayList<Wheel> getWheels() 
    {
       return wheels;
    }

    public void setWheels(ArrayList<Wheel> wheels) 
    {
       this.wheels= wheels;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
       this.type= type;
    }
 }

 public class Wheel
 {
    private String name;        

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setType(String name) {
       this.name= name;
    }
 }
```

That's the Java code.. this is just an example. So i have 3 classes, as u see one is the user that can have one or many cars, then is the car that can have one or many wheels..

In my Spring.xml i want to do something like this..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean id="car1" class="Car">
        <property name="type" value="motorcycle"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="wheel1" class="Wheel">
        <property name="name" value="one"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="wheel2" class="Wheel">
        <property name="name" value="two"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="user1" class="User">
        <property name="name" value="Me"/>
        <property name="cars">
            <list value-type="Car">
                <ref bean="car1">
                  <property name="wheels">
                     <ref bean="wheel1">
                     <ref bean="wheel2">
                  </property">
                </ref>
            </list> 
        </property>
    </bean>
```

If u see this spring.. i want to create the user instance and the cars and wheels by spring-code.. but it won't let me do this.. cause i can't create a ref bean with a property children.. so i can't add wheels to my ref bean car.. how can i do this? or this can't be done this way, maybe is another solution to this.. dunno.. Thanks in advance..

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Why not just set the wheels property on the original `car1` bean definition?

Comment: this is just an example, but imagine that car1 can have one wheel to an user and to another user can have 2 wheels.. in that case i can't do create specifics wheels to a car, thats why i create them in the user instance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set properties on a bean ref, but if you want to be able to reuse the same car instance with a different number of wheels for different users, you can instead make a copies of the car bean using Spring's bean definition inheritance.

In the following XML, we create an *abstract* car definition, then inherit from it and set the wheels property in the user definition(s).

```
<!-- note that original car bean is now marked abstract -->
<bean id="carPrototype" class="Car" abstract="true">
    <property name="type" value="motorcycle"/>
</bean>

<bean id="wheel1" class="Wheel">
    <property name="name" value="one"/>
</bean>
<bean id="wheel2" class="Wheel">
    <property name="name" value="two"/>
</bean>

<bean id="user1" class="User">
    <property name="name" value="Me"/>
    <property name="cars">
        <list value-type="Car">
            <!-- note the use of 'parent' attribute -->
            <bean parent="carPrototype">
                <!-- the type property of "motorcycle" is inherited from the carPrototype definition -->
                <property name="wheels">
                    <ref bean="wheel1">
                    <ref bean="wheel2">
                </property">
            </bean>
        </list> 
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="user2" class="User">
    <property name="name" value="You"/>
    <property name="cars">
        <list value-type="Car">
            <bean parent="carPrototype">
                <!-- the type property of "motorcycle" is inherited from the carPrototype definition -->
                <property name="wheels">
                    <ref bean="wheel1">
                </property">
            </bean>
        </list> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

However, you should note that a nested `<bean>` like above (e.g., the car bean definition is nested inside the user bean definition) is called an *inner* bean, and it cannot have an *id* or *name*.  You also cannot refer to it from anywhere else.  If you want each of your cars to have a bean id, you'd have to make them all top-level beans:

```
<bean id="carPrototype" class="Car" abstract="true">
    <property name="type" value="motorcycle"/>
</bean>

<bean id="car1" parent="carPrototype">
    <!-- the type property of "motorcycle" is inherited from the carPrototype definition -->
    <property name="wheels">
        <ref bean="wheel1">
        <ref bean="wheel2">
    </property">
</bean>

<bean id="car2" parent="carPrototype">
    <!-- the type property of "motorcycle" is inherited from the carPrototype definition -->
    <property name="wheels">
        <ref bean="wheel1">
    </property">
</bean>

<bean id="wheel1" class="Wheel">
    <property name="name" value="one"/>
</bean>
<bean id="wheel2" class="Wheel">
    <property name="name" value="two"/>
</bean>

<bean id="user1" class="User">
    <property name="name" value="Me"/>
    <property name="cars">
        <list value-type="Car">
            <ref bean="car1"/>
        </list> 
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="user2" class="User">
    <property name="name" value="You"/>
    <property name="cars">
        <list value-type="Car">
            <ref bean="car2"/>
        </list> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a Car bean in:

```
<bean id="car1" class="Car">
    <property name="type" value="motorcycle"/>
</bean>
```

For your purpose, I think you should define here the Wheel objects you want, and later just put a reference to this object, Something like:

```
<bean id="car1" class="Car">
    <property name="type" value="motorcycle"/>
    <property name="wheels">
        <list>
            <ref bean="wheel1">
            <ref bean="wheel2">
        </list>
    </property">
</bean>

<bean id="wheel1" class="Wheel">
    <property name="name" value="one"/>
</bean>
<bean id="wheel2" class="Wheel">
    <property name="name" value="two"/>
</bean>

<bean id="user1" class="User">
    <property name="name" value="Me"/>
    <property name="cars" ref="car1"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. but as i said to matts..

"this is just an example, but imagine that car1 can have one wheel to an user and to another user can have 2 wheels.. in that case i can't do create specifics wheels to a car, thats why i create them in the user instance.."

I know i can do that the way you describe but i don't want to specify the wheels in the car instance.. cause it can change from one user to another.. that's why i thought i could created in the user instance.. so that way it would be "dinamyc"

Comment: You create the wheel in <bean id="wheel1" class="Wheel">... In car1 bean definition there are only a reference to that bean (reference could be shared in other Car bean).